# Validator html,неправильное значение атрибута for

Tags: html, for, label

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]нужна помощь,как исправить баг?В чем он заключаеться?
код:

```
<form action="#" class="contacts__form">
                        <div class="contacts__input contacts__name">
                            <input required id="name" type="text">
                            <label for="name">Ваше имя</label>
                        </div>
                              здесь баг/////
                        <div id="email" class="contacts__input contacts__email">
                            <input required type="email">
                            <label for="email">Ваша почта</label>
                        </div>
                               здесь баг/////
                        <div class="contacts__textarea">
                            <textarea name="text" id="text"></textarea>
                            <label for="text">Ваше сообщение</label>
                        </div>

                        <div class="contacts__trigers">
                            <button class="btn">Отправить сообщение</button>
                            <div class="contacts__policy">
                                <input required type="checkbox">
                                <span>Я согласен(а) с <a href="/policy.html"> политикой конфиденциальности</a></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В ошибке явно указано, что в атрибут `for` нужно прописать `ID` элемента.

В разметке видно, что элемент с `id="email"` отсутствует.

При этом, для name `id` указан

```
<input required id="name" type="text">
<label for="name">Ваше имя</label>
```

а для email почему-то нет

```
<input required type="email">
<label for="email">Ваша почта</label>
```